# How do I prevent downloading the same JSON file at runtime?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have two different view controllers that both download the same JSON file from the Internet at runtime in viewDidLoad.

I want to prevent them from downloading the same file twice but instead, use the first JSON file downloaded by the initial view controller to pass it to the second view controller.

This is so that I can shorten my app loading time.

Comment: Make a singleton that downloads and saves the JSON,  and in viewDidLoad of both go and fetch it from singleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this goal, you need to make business logic such as downloading JSON independent from MVC's C(Controller).

Usually add a class file named XXXModel. Use this Model as a singleton. In this singleton you will need to implement functions of downloading and saving JSON data. You'd better save JSON data to local with a key named after its URL.

And in your Controllers, always call the singleton to download JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a singleton dictionary with url as key and bool as the value then save true for downloaded url. that way, you can keep track of which url's contents u have

```
   var isDownloaded = [NSURL : Bool] // singleton in appdelegate 

   if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
      if isDownloaded[url] != nil && !isDownloaded[url]! {
         if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: []) {
             let json = JSON(data: data)
             isDownloaded.updateValue(true, forKey: url) //mark it back to false if you delete the data for some reason.
         }
      } else {
           //get it from memory
      }
   }
```